Why Docker doesn't start automatically?
I run Docker container on Proxmox (Alpine Linux 3.19).
The following command is used to start the Docker:
docker run -d --name=firefox -p 5900:5900 -e DISPLAY_WIDTH=1024 -e DISPLAY_HEIGHT=768 -e FF_OPEN_URL=http://192.168.1.110:8123 -e FF_KIOSK=1 -v /docker/appdata/firefox:/config:rw jlesage/firefox

And the following to have it started automatically with PC reboot:
docker update --restart unless-stopped firefox

But when PC is started, I am unable to connect with VNC to my Docker.
If I try to run it manually, I get the following error:

docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name
"/firefox" is already in use by container
"eb612b8a245428d930ed4ecf16847c6edd99234fc7e1811ec2f8900cb4eba5d5".
You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that
name.

Looks like it is running.
Then I stop and remove the container and run it again. After that I am able to connect.
What could be a reason?
